# Unwelcome string at start and end of XML output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm exporting XML directly to file, to avoid the time it takes to render to view, and it's working nicely:

controller:

```
  def onixout
        s = render_to_string(:template=>"isbns/onix.xml.builder") 
        send_data(s, :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "onix2.1.xml")       
  end
```

The Builder file is pretty standard:

```
xml.instruct!(:xml, :version => "1.0", :encoding => "utf-8")
xml.declare! :DOCTYPE, :ONIXMessage, :SYSTEM, "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/03/reference/onix-international.dtd"
xml.ONIXMessage do
  xml.Header do 
    if Company.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).first.nil?
    else
      xml.FromCompany Company.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).first.sendername 
  end 
  end 
   Isbn.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).search(params[:q]).result.all.each do |isbn|
    xml.Product do
      xml.NotificationType isbn.notificationtype unless isbn.notificationtype.blank? 
        isbn.productcodes.each do |productcode| 
          xml.ProductIdentifier do   
#more
```

In the resultant file, though, I'm getting an undesirable string at the start (e047d in this case):

```
e047d
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ONIXMessage SYSTEM "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/03/reference/onix-international.dtd">
<ONIXMessage>
  <Header>
#more
```

And there's a '0' at the end of the doc too.

Any idea what they are? And, obviously, how to get rid?

Comment: that's probably because of the BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Look at php support for the iconv api to do conversion (or to detect encoding from stream while reading)

Comment: This is a rails question, but thanks, that's great - bound to be the problem. I'll investigate!

Comment: The 0 at the end is probably a nul byte too.  Not sure why it is appearing as the glyph zero though.